# When Should Data be Included in its own Model in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, architecture, model

When should Data be included in its own Model in Rails and when can it just be added as a column to a current Model?

For example, lets say I want to add a Paid Membership option to Users. Should I create a new Model Membership and let Users `has_one Membership`, OR should I just add a couple of columns to User: `boolean membership` and an `date expiration` (and maybe a `boolean auto-renew`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the future. As you just said in your question, "maybe a `boolean auto-renew`" is already another option you want to add on the user-membership system.

Also, a user-membership may need more options in the future (like the `auto-renew`, or a history system to keep a trace of when the user was a member, for how long, etc.).

- If you want a **flexible** (easy to add options/methods/attributes/stuff) **membership system**, you should create a `UserMembership` model. (You could have a history of the memberships of the users, that can be very useful for stats).
- If you just need a **small membership system** with only one or two options (but try to think in the future!), you could just add a column `expiration_date` and when it is `nil`, it means the User has no membership (so no need fo the `boolean membership`), if there is a value then it is/was a member, and if this `expiration_date > Date.today` then the user is still a Member.

Comment: Let's say I ended up needing to add 4 columns (after a while). Would it be so bad if they were all attached to User and nil for non-members?

Comment: It is not "bad" to have a lot of nil values. But it proves that a Model could have been more suitable in this situation. Also, adding 4 columns just for "one" system, it is a lot! I think you should make a Model of it with these 4 columns ;) @am-rails